# RecyclerView with SQLite in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I am building a to-do-list App in android. 
The list has tasks. 
A task in the list contains of (title , description) both Strings And saved as Task object in an ArrayList.

**Important** :
The Tasks are saved as an **ArrayList** and kept in a SQLite data base and shown in RecyclerView.

When I try to get the data back from the data base and list them in the RecyclerView the App stops.
I tried to debug the code and as I saw it stops while adding elements to the ArrayList "tasks".
I don't know what is wrong in the code.

```
public class Listing extends AppCompatActivity implements TaskAdapter.ItemClicked {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.Adapter myAdapter;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    ArrayList<Task> tasks;

    DatabaseHelper myDB;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_listing);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.list);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        // setting layout maneger
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        myDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        Cursor data = myDB.getListContents();
        if (data.getCount() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(Listing.this, "no elements", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            while (data.moveToNext()) {

                Task task = new Task(data.getString(1), data.getString(2));
                tasks.add(task);

                myAdapter = new TaskAdapter(this, tasks);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Post the error log.

Comment: @forpas I have just posted the Logcat

Comment: Even if you solved the problem move these lines: `myAdapter = new TaskAdapter(this, tasks); recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);` right after the while block because you must set the adapter only once after you fill the list and not for every item that you add to the list.

Comment: @forpas makes sense
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just found that I have forgot to initialize the ArrayList which was causing all the problems